# How to make gallery as like turn paper in book?

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I am trying to make gallery view just like turning pages in a book. So kindly give me some suggestions.

Comment: Use a ViewFlipper when animating: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Comment: you can easily create a HTML5 book using this plugin http://www.turnjs.com/

Comment: Here'a another project, which serves exactly this purpose - https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Comment: i go along with Tahir Yasin, personally for such purpose i use turn.js

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is called a page curl or flip animation. There are plenty of open source libraries to implement this. You can try any of these:

1. [android-page-curl](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl)
2. [Android-Flip](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip)
3. [page-curl-harism](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/)
4. [3d-flip](https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/)

Good luck !

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked for you !

Comment: The first link is very useful for me.